# Confused with CHMODE in my PC and another PC

Tags: php, chmod

I have a simple question about CHMOD.

Here is the code:

```
$dstfile='\\\\192.168.183.6\\test\test1';

echo chmod($dstfile,01777);
```

When I tried to open it in My PC, it's worked, no error.

Then I try to install xampp in another PC, then I copy the source to local. When I tried to open it, it show error like this :

```
Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory in...
```

Whereas that address \\192.168.183.6\test\test1 is exist and proven in my PC it's worked.

I already set folder permission for each Users in security and sharing for full access.

Any advice guys?
I really confused about that.

Note: My PC (OS is Windows 7 and another PC is Windows XP)

Comment: Is the "other PC" on the same local network? Can you access that file from that PC from outside your code? Are you aware of what IPs starting with `192.168` are?

Comment: @Wooble YES in same local network, I can open that file outside my code. The IP is in class scope. Another PC IP example : 192.168.183.20

Comment: Which OS is the other PC using?

Comment: Windows XP, is it possible the problem from PHP version? But why in my PC it's OK... headache :(